# MySQL update or insert for tables without primary key

Tags: mysql

I know the simple way to perform update or insert is using 'REPLACE' but it needs a primary key, how about in the case of a table without primary key?

I have 5 columns in my table:

1. remark_id(the auto-increment primary key)
2. user_id
3. remark_user_id
4. remark
5. last_modified

I wish to check whether the pair of `user_id` and `remark_user_id` exists first before updating the remark, else a new row will be created to save the remark with the `user_id` and `remark_user_id`.

Here's my code

```
INSERT INTO `users_remark` (`user_id`, `remark_user_id`, `remark`) 
SELECT 1,3 ,'testing123'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM `users_remark`
     WHERE `user_id` = 1
       AND `remark_user_id` = 3)
```

After running the SQL, nothing happens in my Database. No record was added or updated.

**[Edited]**

Code changes using `IF...ELSE...` but it comes with some syntax errors on first line

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users_remark WHERE user_id' at line 1

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `users_remark` 
    WHERE `user_id`=1 AND `remark_user_id` = 3
    )
    THEN    UPDATE `users_remark` SET `remark` = 'testing123' 
            WHERE `user_id`=1 AND `remark_user_id` = 3
ELSE
    INSERT INTO `users_remark` SET `remark` = 'testing123', `user_id`=1, `remark_user_id` = 3
```

Comment: If this query has a result: `SELECT * FROM users_remark WHERE user_id = 1 AND remark_user_id = 3` It's normal that nothing happens because of the `NOT EXISTS` clause. And just for info, an `INSERT` statement will never do an `UPDATE`.

Comment: how about updating case??? how should it be edited?

Comment: To proceed an update on your table: `UPDATE users_remark SET remark = 'testing123' WHERE user_id = 1 AND remark_user_id = 3`

Comment: No, I mean update if exists and insert if not exists, how should the code be edited??

Comment: You need to have two separate queries, one for the INSERT clause and a second one for the UPDATE clause. Use an `IF...ELSE...` statement to determine which one needs to be executed.

Comment: edited but a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query with both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` clauses **(T-SQL syntax)**:

```
IF [condition here] BEGIN
     UPDATE `users_remark`
     SET `remark` = 'testing123' 
     WHERE `user_id`=1
         AND `remark_user_id` = 3
END
ELSE BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `users_remark` (`user_id`, `remark_user_id`, `remark`)
    VALUES (1, 3, 'testing123)
END
```

**EDIT: Same query with MySQL syntax**

```
DECLARE @numrecords INT

SELECT @numrecords = count(*)
FROM `users_remark`
WHERE `user_id` = 1
   AND `remark_user_id` = 3

IF @numrecords > 0 THEN
     UPDATE `users_remark`
     SET `remark` = 'testing123' 
     WHERE `user_id`=1
         AND `remark_user_id` = 3
ELSE
    INSERT INTO `users_remark` (`user_id`, `remark_user_id`, `remark`)
    VALUES (1, 3, 'testing123)
END IF
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM `users_remark` 
           WHERE `user_id`' at line 1

Comment: Sorry for the syntax, i'm working with T-SQL and the syntax is a bit different for MySQL. I updated my answer with the MySQL version

Comment: Sorry for that, i simplified the answer by focusing only on what you're looking for (`INSERT/UPDATE` logic).

Comment: Thank you very much...but what should the condition be in my case?? I have a syntax error here.

Comment: Your condition should test if the pair `user_id` and `remark_user_id` already exists in the table.

Comment: I put EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `users_remark` 
    WHERE `user_id`=1 AND `remark_user_id` = 3
    ) into the condition field but it says syntax error occur

Comment: This syntax works for T-SQL but for MySQL you can't do it the same way. You need to declare a variable to store the count or `EXISTS` state and then use this variable in your `IF` clause.

Comment: I'm not sure about the MySQL syntax but after a quick search in the Manual, i think that my updated query is well formed. I first declare a variable, set it with the count corresponding to your parameters and then i use this variable for the `IF` clause. Hope that it will help you

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @numrecords INT

Comment: By the way, I have solved the problem by myself. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide me the issue with my query so i can fix it? It can be helpful for other users

Comment: the query seems have a syntax error as report in comment

Answer (score 0):

I finally try on putting code to php, it works and much easier to understand.

```
        $checkRemark = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_conn'], "SELECT * FROM `users_remark` WHERE `user_id`=".$data['uid']." AND `remark_user_id` = ".$data['ruid']);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($checkRemark)>0){
            $remarkSql = "UPDATE `users_remark`
                         SET `remark` = '".$data['remark']."' 
                         WHERE `user_id`=".$data['uid']."
                             AND `remark_user_id` = ".$data['ruid'];
        } else {
            $remarkSql = "INSERT INTO `users_remark` (`user_id`, `remark_user_id`, `remark`)
                            VALUES (".$data['uid'].", ".$data['ruid'].", '".$data['remark']."')";
        }
```